# DataFrame AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'date'

Tags: python, pandas

I can confirm I set the index to my dataframe

```
df.set_index('time_date', inplace=True)
df.head()
                  Unnamed: 0    lid t_user_id   collected_time  latitude    longitude   altitude    transportation_mode
time_date                               
2008-04-01 11:30:37-03:00   0   1   10  2008-04-01 11:30:37-03  39.475128   75.999173   -777.0  walk
2008-04-01 11:31:38-03:00   1   1   10  2008-04-01 11:31:38-03  39.474785   75.999100   -777.0  walk
2008-04-01 11:32:37-03:00   2   1   10  2008-04-01 11:32:37-03  39.474385   75.999417   -777.0  walk
2008-04-01 11:33:36-03:00   3   1   10  2008-04-01 11:33:36-03  39.473852   75.999690   -777.0  walk
2008-04-01 11:34:35-03:00   4   1   10  2008-04-01 11:34:35-03  39.473417   76.000253   -777.0  walk
```

However, everytime I pass the dataframe to a myclass object, I get this error message.

```
ts_obj = ts.TrajectorySegmentation(df)
ts_obj.load_data()
65         # sort data first
     66         #self.raw_data=self.raw_data.sort_index()
---> 67         self.row_data['day'] = self.row_data.index.date
     68 
     69         # preprocessing

AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'date'
```

Class definition:`enter code here`

```
class TrajectorySegmentation:
    def __init__(self, rowData=pd.DataFrame()):
        self.row_data = rowData

    def load_data(self, **kwargs):
        src = self.row_data
```

I cannot figure out what wrong with the line 67 in the library that python complain about, but here is fragment containing line 67

```
65  # sort data first
66  #self.raw_data=self.raw_data.sort_index()
67  self.row_data['day'] = self.row_data.index.date
68
```

EDIT

Tried one of the answers, same error, screenshot:
[image]

**EDIT-2**

sample data

```
!cat sample.csv
time_date,Unnamed: 0,lid,t_user_id,collected_time,latitude,longitude,altitude,transportation_mode
2008-04-01 11:30:37-03:00,0,1,10,2008-04-01 11:30:37-03,39.47512800000001,75.999173,-777.0,walk
2008-04-01 11:31:38-03:00,1,1,10,2008-04-01 11:31:38-03,39.474785,75.9991,-777.0,walk
2008-04-01 11:32:37-03:00,2,1,10,2008-04-01 11:32:37-03,39.474385,75.99941700000002,-777.0,walk
2008-04-01 11:33:36-03:00,3,1,10,2008-04-01 11:33:36-03,39.473852,75.99969,-777.0,walk
2008-04-01 11:34:35-03:00,4,1,10,2008-04-01 11:34:35-03,39.473417,76.000253,-777.0,walk
```

Comment: Your datetime format seems incorrect. Try to get it to a datetime format? Also check by doing an iloc or dtypes before setting index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your `time_date` column isn't being converted to a datetime64 object. Try adding `utc=True` to `pd.to_datetime`.

This snippet works:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', delimiter=',', header=0, index_col=False)

# convert time_date col to datetime64 dtype
df['time_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_date'], utc=True)

df.set_index('time_date', inplace=True)

print(df.index.date)
```

**Output**

```
[datetime.date(2008, 4, 1) datetime.date(2008, 4, 1)
 datetime.date(2008, 4, 1) datetime.date(2008, 4, 1)
 datetime.date(2008, 4, 1)]
```

**Edit:** You can use [`df.info()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html) to double check that your columns are the correct dtypes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can work around it by using the `apply` function on the Pandas series passing in the function `lambda x: x.date`?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you set index before making `time_date` a datetime object. Please try

Data based on your post

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'collected_time':['2008-04-01 11:30:37-03','2008-04-01 11:31:38-03','2008-04-02 11:32:37-03','2008-04-01 11:33:36-03'],'val':[23,76,2,45]})
```

Coerce `collected_time` to datetime

```
df['collected_time']=pd.to_datetime(df['collected_time'])
df.dtypes#Check dataframe data types
```

#Set Index

```
df.set_index('collected_time', inplace=True)
```

Extract date from index

```
df['date']=df.index.date
```

[image]

Comment: That should work if all the values of time_date are as shown. Can you please post sample data with a variety of dates that is if the dates are varied

Comment: Cant make sense of recent data posted. Do you want to copy the date object you want indexed and maybe one other colum and put as sample. Else, can follow my rework above.